# SQL insert into - from different server and credentials

Tags: sql-server, select, insert, credentials

We have one database existing on server A.  Server A also hosts our program code which will be calling the SQL statement.

We have another database `VMIntranetTest` existing on server B `VMC-MMS`

Server A and server B have different logon user credentials.  Server A and server B both exist on our internal network.

Using PHP, I have the following SQL statement defined.

```
$strSql = 'INSERT INTO VMC-MMS.VMIntranetTest.dbo.TestTable (FirstName, LastName, Age) ' .
                    'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, AGE ' .
                    'FROM BSLIB.SQLTSTF ';
```

`FROM -> BSLIB.SQLTSTF <-` is on our local server (A), so my connection string used to execute the statement will have the user credentials to connect to server A.

`INSERT INTO -> VMC-MMS.VMIntranetTest.dbo.TestTable <-` is the different server.database.dbo.table (Server B).

How do I specify the user credentials to be used for the  INSERT INTO portion of the statement?  The secondary portion containing the SELECT FROM statement should already be covered by my initial connection string.

Thank you,

**Edit 1** in regards to Paul's answer.

I've attempted to use the `OPENROWSET` as mentioned, and have the following SQL statement.

```
INSERT INTO VMIntranetTest.TestTable (FirstName, LastName, Age)
OPENROWSET('vmas400',
           'Server=192.168.1.2;Trusted_Connection=yes;user_id=INTRAIS;password=****',
           'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, AGE FROM BSLIB.SQLTSTF' ) as a
```

As you can see, I changed things around a little bit.  My connection string through the code opens the connection to Server B "VMC-MMS".  My SQL statement "select" portion, uses the OPENROWSET to open a connection to Server A "192.168.1.2".

However, I am getting this error message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "OPENROWSET": syntax error

**Edit 2**  i needed to put the entire OPENROWSET portion inside a VALUES (    )  clause.  Now I'm getting a message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: VMIntranetTest.TestTable

**Edit 3**

I've now got the following SQL

```
 INSERT INTO VMIntranetTest.TestTable (FirstName, LastName, Age)
 select a.FNAME, a.LNAME, a.AGE FROM 
 OPENROWSET('vmas400',
            'Server=192.168.1.2;Trusted_Connection=yes;user_id=INTRAIS;password=****',
            'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, AGE FROM BSLIB.SQLTSTF' ) as a
```

And am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "(": syntax error

Comment: Why are you putting these queries together in the same DB call?  They aren't dependent on one another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need the `SELECT` statement in there. Try this:

```
INSERT INTO VMIntranetTest.dbo.TestTable (a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Age)
SELECT a.FirstName, a.LastName, a.Age FROM
OPENROWSET('vmas400',
           'Server=192.168.1.2;Trusted_Connection=yes;user_id=INTRAIS;password=****',
           'SELECT FNAME, LNAME, AGE FROM BSLIB.dbo.SQLTSTF' ) as a
```

EDIT: Try the query now. You had the table specified from the database without specifying the schema. If you have appropriate permissions, the above query will now work. Otherwise, you will need to specify the schema. Sorry for not catching that!

Comment: Hi Zach, I've tried this suggestion, but am getting a syntax error... although I'm not sure why I am getting the specific error.  Please see my Edit #3 to my original post.  thanks for the help!!

Comment: Is this MS SQL that you're using?

Comment: Its a sql server 2005, but the connection type is of PDO SQLITE.  Not sure if that is what you were after?

Comment: Try it now with the DB schema specified. Let us know if that works!

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I'm not familiar with specifying schmeas.  I'll start looking into that, but for a quick help, do i just use what you have edited with the two simultanious  ..'s ?

Comment: It's shorthand in MS-SQL. Not sure if it works in SQLite, so I changed it to .dbo in my answer. Hope it works!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11885/discussion-between-zach-and-adam)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `OPENROWSET` to select data from the different database

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

Comment: This appears to be what I'm looking for!!  I will read about how to use this, try it out, and post back with results :)  thank you!

Comment: Hi Paul.  Thank you for the response, i feel like it is very close, however I'm getting a syntax error.  Please see my updated OP.  thanks!

Comment: yes, as @zach has commented, you need to `select from` the rowset