# Transfer data from local server to online server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 on my local PC. In my database there is one table with approx 98000 rows. Now I want to transfer that data directly to online server database. I have tried by making script of that table but when I run that script, it gives me error of insufficient memory. plz help me.. how can I do this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of strategies you can employ in this instance.  Here's a few off the top of my head...

- Got some .NET programming up your sleeve?  [Try the SqlBulkCopy class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx)
- Export the data to a transferable format, e.g. CSV file and then use [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to insert the data.
- Try using [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) to copy from the local to remote. [Stackoverflow example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800288/sql-insert-into-from-different-server-and-credentials)
- If you've got the full leverage of SSIS, example [of SSIS is just here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/05/12/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-database-table-using-ssis/)
- A bit [Heath Robinson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Heath_Robinson) but why not grab the data out into CSV and using some Excel skills, build the individual statements yourself.  Example [here using INSERT INTO and UNION](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/08/sql-server-insert-multiple-records-using-one-insert-statement-use-of-union-all/)

HTH